# Pastas no Jupyter

Tags: ipython-notebook

Sempre usei o pycharm, e estou usando o jupyter agora, e gostaria de saber onde ficam as pastas que eu crio nele.

Entrei nele, criei algumas pastas no diretório documentos, mas eles não aparecem no meu computador apenas dentro do Jupyter, pensei que fossem pastas compartilhadas do meu pc com o jupyter

Answer (score 1):

### Diretório

Os documentos e as pastas que você cria no Jupyter Notebook fica no diretório que você chamou o Jupyter Notebook

### Exemplo

Inicializei o Jupyter Notebook no caminho `C:\Users\Kaique Nakao\Desktop\Stack OverFlow>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivos criados no Jupyter Notebook:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivos no diretório  `C:\Users\Kaique Nakao\Desktop\Stack OverFlow>` onde que eu inicializei o Jupyter Notebook

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]